# refresh div with wire:ignore in laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-livewire

we used a vue component in livewire component . vue component is DatePicker :

```
      <div  id="customDiv" class="col-12 col-md-6 m-1" wire:ignore>
        <date-picker v-model="date"
                     :disable="[{{$disableDateString}}]" @input="changeDate">
        ></date-picker>
    </div>
```

we should refresh component after date submit to add disable dates in Vue Component again.
I set a listener in livewire component for refreshing component ,but it doesnt affect on div with wire:ignore .
is there anuy way to refresh vue component without any error or hiding from view ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's the thing. `wire:ignore` will tell Livewire "*don't update this element or it's children*".

The simplest way about this would be to use Alpine and then *entangle* that property between the two, thereby moving the responsibility for updating that to Alpine, which doesn't care about `wire:ignore`.

```html
<div 
    id="customDiv" 
    class="col-12 col-md-6 m-1" 
    wire:ignore
    x-data="{ disableDateString: @entangle('disableDateString') }"
>
    <date-picker 
        v-model="date"
        x-bind:disable="[disableDateString]" 
        @input="changeDate">
    ></date-picker>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't uses Alpaine, I used Vue, can I use code in Vue without adding alpinejs?

Comment: You already have Alpine.js, it comes with Livewire. So you can use that. If you want to use Vue, you can, but nothing inside `wire:ignore` will re-render. Meaning that the print from the PHP variable will not change, so you have to move it outside somehow. Easiest approach is to use Alpine